# Including missing combinations of values in a pandas groupby aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

**Problem**

Including all possible values or combinations of values in the output of a pandas groupby aggregation.

**Example**

Example pandas DataFrame has three columns, `User`, `Code`, and `Subtotal`:

```
import pandas as pd
example_df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 1], ['a', 2, 1], ['b', 1, 1], ['b', 2, 1], ['c', 1, 1], ['c', 1, 1]], columns=['User', 'Code', 'Subtotal'])
```

I'd like to group on `User` and `Code` and get a subtotal for each combination of `User` and `Code`.

```
print(example_df.groupby(['User', 'Code']).Subtotal.sum().reset_index())
```

The output I get is:

```
  User   Code   Subtotal
0    a      1          1
1    a      2          1
2    b      1          1
3    b      2          1
4    c      1          2
```

How can I include the missing combination `User=='c'` and `Code==2` in the table, even though it doesn't exist in `example_df`?

**Preferred output**

Below is the preferred output, with a zero line for the `User=='c'` and `Code==2` combination.

```
  User   Code   Subtotal
0    a      1          1
1    a      2          1
2    b      1          1
3    b      2          1
4    c      1          2
5    c      2          0
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
print(example_df.groupby(['User', 'Code']).Subtotal.sum()
                .unstack(fill_value=0)
                .stack()
                .reset_index(name='Subtotal'))
  User  Code  Subtotal
0    a     1         1
1    a     2         1
2    b     1         1
3    b     2         1
4    c     1         2
5    c     2         0
```

Another solution with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by `MultiIndex` created [`from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df = example_df.groupby(['User', 'Code']).Subtotal.sum()
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names=['User','Code'])
print (mux)
MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=['User', 'Code'])

print (df.reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index(name='Subtotal'))
  User  Code  Subtotal
0    a     1         1
1    a     2         1
2    b     1         1
3    b     2         1
4    c     1         2
5    c     2         0
```

Answer (score 2):

One can achieve this in a simple way by using pandas's [categorical type](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html), which will trigger the `groupby` to include all possible values of the categorical column.

```py
import pandas as pd
example_df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 1], ['a', 2, 1], ['b', 1, 1], ['b', 2, 1], ['c', 1, 1], ['c', 1, 1]], columns=['User', 'Code', 'Subtotal']

# make `User` col into category type
example_df["User"] = example_df["User"].astype("category")

# now groupby will include all `User` value by default
print(example_df.groupby(['User', 'Code']).Subtotal.sum().reset_index())
```

gives

```
  User  Code  Subtotal
0    a     1         1
1    a     2         1
2    b     1         1
3    b     2         1
4    c     1         2
5    c     2         0
```

as desired.

[Reference to behaviour in docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html):

> Groupby will also show “unused” categories:

Note that this behaviour can be disabled by passing `observed=True` to `DataFrame.groupby` [ref](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).