# Including missing combination of values based on a group of grouped data

Tags: python, pandas

I am expanding on earlier thread: [Including missing combinations of values in a pandas groupby aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854801/including-missing-combinations-of-values-in-a-pandas-groupby-aggregation)

In above thread, the accepted answer computes all possible combinations for the grouping variable. In this version, I'd like to compute combinations based on group of groups.

Let's take an example.

Here's input dataframe:

[image]

Here, one group is `[Year,Quarter]` i.e.

```
Year  Quarter
2014  Q1
2015  Q2
2015  Q3
```

Another set of group is `Name`:

```
Name
Adam
Smith
```

Now, I want to apply `groupby` and `sum` such that missing values of the combination of above groups is detected as `NaN`

Here's sample output:

[image]

I'd appreciate any help.

---

Here's sample `input` and `output` in `dict` format:

```
input=
{'Year': {0: 2014, 1: 2014, 2: 2015, 3: 2015, 4: 2015},
 'Quarter': {0: 'Q1', 1: 'Q1', 2: 'Q2', 3: 'Q2', 4: 'Q3'},
 'Name': {0: 'Adam', 1: 'Smith', 2: 'Adam', 3: 'Adam', 4: 'Smith'},
 'Value': {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 5, 4: 5}}

output=
{'Year': {0: 2014, 1: 2014, 2: 2015, 3: 2015, 4: 2015, 5: 2015},
 'Quarter': {0: 'Q1', 1: 'Q1', 2: 'Q2', 3: 'Q2', 4: 'Q3', 5: 'Q3'},
 'Name': {0: 'Adam', 1: 'Smith', 2: 'Adam', 3: 'Smith', 4: 'Smith', 5: 'Adam'},
 'Value': {0: 2.0, 1: 3.0, 2: 9.0, 3: nan, 4: 5.0, 5: nan}}
```

**Clarification:**

I am looking for a method without doing melt and cast. i.e. without playing around with long and wide format.

Answer (score 1):

The example post you posted is the correct answer: `groupby` get the `sum` then `unstack` to find the missing value then `stack` with the param `dropna=False` here are the docs on [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

```
df.groupby(['Year','Quarter','Name']).sum().unstack().stack(dropna=False).reset_index()

    Year    Quarter   Name   Value
0   2014    Q1        Adam   2.0
1   2014    Q1        Smith  3.0
2   2015    Q2        Adam   9.0
3   2015    Q2        Smith  NaN
4   2015    Q3        Adam   NaN
5   2015    Q3        Smith  5.0
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Interestingly, I think the issue is that method 2 on that thread doesn't work. I see that method 1 works.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pivot_table`, PS you can add `reset_index` at the end

```
df.pivot_table(index=['Year','Quarter'],columns='Name',values='Value',aggfunc='sum').stack(dropna=False)
Year  Quarter  Name 
2014  Q1       Adam     2.0
               Smith    3.0
2015  Q2       Adam     9.0
               Smith    NaN
      Q3       Adam     NaN
               Smith    5.0
dtype: float64
```